# Spliting String with multi comma

Tags: javascript, regex

How is it splitted below text? It contains comma seperated values but some inner values has also comma. However we know that each group starts with `GO:XX` pattern.

> GO:0048193, BP, Golgi vesicle transport, GO:0030198, BP, extracellular
> matrix organization, GO:0006903, BP, vesicle targeting, GO:0043062,
> BP, extracellular structure organization, **GO:0048199, BP, vesicle
> targeting, to, from or within Golgi,** GO:0031012, CC, extracellular
> matrix, GO:0062023, CC, collagen-containing extracellular matrix,
> GO:0005581, CC, collagen trimer, GO:0044420, CC, extracellular matrix
> component, GO:0030020, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent
> conferring tensile strength, GO:0005201, MF, extracellular matrix
> structural constituent

I used this regex pattern but not working for multi comma values: (like in GO:0048199)

```js
let myRegexp = /(GO:[0-9]+), (BP|MF|CC), ([^,]+)/g;
let raw = "GO:0048193, BP, Golgi vesicle transport, GO:0030198, BP, extracellular matrix organization, GO:0006903, BP, vesicle targeting, GO:0043062, BP, extracellular structure organization, GO:0048199, BP, vesicle targeting, to, from or within Golgi, GO:0031012, CC, extracellular matrix, GO:0062023, CC, collagen-containing extracellular matrix, GO:0005581, CC, collagen trimer, GO:0044420, CC, extracellular matrix component, GO:0030020, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent conferring tensile strength, GO:0005201, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent"
let match = myRegexp.exec(raw);
while (match != null) {
      console.log(match[0].trim());
      match = myRegexp.exec(raw);
}
```

Maybe I can split data with pattern: `GO:[0-9]+` but then I couldn't capture GO IDs. It will be two steps two capture all data so it is ugly code. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Does the second item always have 2 letters?

Comment: @Andrew I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a lookahead:

```
GO:\d+.*?(?=,\s+GO:|$)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jp2eLs/1/).

---

In `JS` this could be:

```js
let myRegexp = /GO:\d+.*?(?=,\s+GO:|$)/g;
let raw = "GO:0048193, BP, Golgi vesicle transport, GO:0030198, BP, extracellular matrix organization, GO:0006903, BP, vesicle targeting, GO:0043062, BP, extracellular structure organization, GO:0048199, BP, vesicle targeting, to, from or within Golgi, GO:0031012, CC, extracellular matrix, GO:0062023, CC, collagen-containing extracellular matrix, GO:0005581, CC, collagen trimer, GO:0044420, CC, extracellular matrix component, GO:0030020, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent conferring tensile strength, GO:0005201, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent"
let match = myRegexp.exec(raw);
while (match != null) {
      console.log(match[0].trim());
      match = myRegexp.exec(raw);
}
```

Comment: You can directly use `raw.match(myRegexp)`.

Comment: @iota: OK. I'm not really into `JS`. Feel free to change the code in the answer.

Comment: It runs but I couldn't understand ? operator. I will research it, thank you.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimOymacı: It is called a *lazy quantifier*, that is match as *few* characters as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string by taking positive lookahead.

```js
let raw = "GO:0048193, BP, Golgi vesicle transport, GO:0030198, BP, extracellular matrix organization, GO:0006903, BP, vesicle targeting, GO:0043062, BP, extracellular structure organization, GO:0048199, BP, vesicle targeting, to, from or within Golgi, GO:0031012, CC, extracellular matrix, GO:0062023, CC, collagen-containing extracellular matrix, GO:0005581, CC, collagen trimer, GO:0044420, CC, extracellular matrix component, GO:0030020, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent conferring tensile strength, GO:0005201, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent",
    result = raw.split(/,\s+(?=GO:\d+,)/);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Like previous answer you use ?= operator. What does it mean? Thank you too.

Comment: it is the positive lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = 'GO:0048193, BP, Golgi vesicle transport, GO:0030198, BP, extracellular matrix organization, GO:0006903, BP, vesicle targeting, GO:0043062, BP, extracellular structure organization, GO:0048199, BP, vesicle targeting, to, from or within Golgi, GO:0031012, CC, extracellular matrix, GO:0062023, CC, collagen-containing extracellular matrix, GO:0005581, CC, collagen trimer, GO:0044420, CC, extracellular matrix component, GO:0030020, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent conferring tensile strength, GO:0005201, MF, extracellular matrix structural constituent'

const result = input.split('GO:00').slice(1).map(x => 'GO:00' + x)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: It will not be run if GO IDs starts with non zero number like that GO:123345. It should be generic.